# A Splity Situation

Tags: riddle, knowledge, geography

I use to be one

But now that is done

Now I am feeling rationed out

Wine party is over, bummer about

---

Father is large, mother is small

Both were once isolated and all

But with this, records stand no more

As of now, they share sides

---

Near top of the world

I am visited sparse

The few who came were cheerful

Despite some being enemies

---

With a clink of sea salty glass,

I drink one last drink of change

And face my future destiny

To world peace!

---

Where am I? Please explain each line!

Comment: Most of this could be rot13(gur Gvgnavp) but I don't get the father/mother line if so

Comment: @Amoz No, that is not it. This riddle pertains to recent events.

Comment: Is the title a reference to rot13(gur pvgl ba gur Nqevngvp Frn)?

Comment: @xyldke Nope, nope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are

> [Hans Island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hans_Island)

I use to be one
But now that is done
Now I am feeling rationed out

> The island, located off the coast of Greenland, was formerly a disputed territory, with Canada and Denmark laying claim to it. They have now agreed to split the island in two.

Wine party is over, bummer about

> As part of the dispute, in 1984, the Danish Prime Minister planted a flag and reportedly left a bottle of brandy, which is a liquor distilled from wine.

Father is large, mother is small

> The father is Canada, the larger of the two countries.

Both were once isolated and all
But with this, records stand no more
As of now, they share sides
Near top of the world

> The island is located in the Nares Strait, approximately 80° north latitude.

I am visited sparse
The few who came were cheerful
Despite some being enemies

> The island is uninhabited, with the only visitors being researchers and officials from Canada and Denmark, alternating visits to plant their country's flags and leave notes and liquor, laying claim to the island.

With a clink of sea salty glass,
I drink one last drink of change
And face my future destiny
To world peace!

> On June 14, 2022, a treaty was signed by the Canadian and Danish governments, splitting the island between the two countries.

Answer (score 0):

You are:

> Russia / the former Soviet Union

I use to be one
But now that is done
Now I am feeling rationed out
Wine party is over, bummer about

> Once unified as the USSR, this was broken up into smaller countries following its dissolution.

Father is large, mother is small
Both were once isolated and all
But with this, records stand no more
As of now, they share sides

> The USSR was referred to as a fatherland, but 'mother' Russia.

Near top of the world
I am visited sparse
The few who came were cheerful
Despite some being enemies

> Russia and connected 'eastern bloc' countries are near the 'top of the world' in that they are in the northern hemisphere. Some of Russia's territory is among the most northerly.

With a clink of sea salty glass,
I drink one last drink of change
And face my future destiny
To world peace!

> Peace indeed.

Comment: Er, not that country, sorry.

Comment: @RewanDemontay updated.

Comment: I meant as in not Ukraine/USSR at all.